# How to ignore a CSV delimiter within a quoted field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV data dump that is formated like this:

```
"field1";"{"JSON-KEY": "JSON-VALUE"}";"field3"
```

If I use the CSV Python reader like this...

```
csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
```

I'm having two problems:

(1) When a **JSON-VALUE** string contains the *delimiter* character ';' the Reader considers it as a delimiter and break the VALUE in two fields.

(2) When (1) is not a problem, the JSON-VALUE field is misinterpreted to have one quote less at the begining and one more at the end. For instance:

```
 ['field1','{JSON-KEY": "JSON-VALUE"}"','field3']
```

These two problems are probably related, but I can't fix this by using Python documentation and other Questions here. Does anyone have a lead to what am I missing here and how can I configure the Reader to handle this?

Comment: The CSV format here seems to be ambiguous. Some of your quotes are CSV quotes, others are part of the actual data—and not escaped. Unless there's some non-obvious rule that you haven't explained, the only way to parse that is with guesswork. Is it possible to fix the data dump to produce a valid CSV file in the first place?

Comment: If not, you might be able to come up with some guesswork that works. For example, if you first scan every line looking for semicolons that appear inside quotes and escape them with an escape character, then create a CSV reader that does not use `"` as a quote character and does use that escape character, that combination of two steps would be able to parse this example, and it might work for your whole dump. (Or it might not; without seeing it, or testing it, it's hard to say.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the csv data is invalid. The quotes should be escaped like this:

```
"field1";"{""JSON-KEY"": ""JSON-VALUE""}";"field3"
```

If you have no control over the generation of the csv data, you could try to use `quotechar=''` and then trim the quotes from the fields.

If there are `;` in the json data however, that would be problematic.

Another option then would be to manually read the first and last field, and consider the data between those as the json data.

Comment: Indeed I had access to changing the CSV and by escaping the quotes things just worked fine.